# stuck with moving my XTZ to Temple wallet

Tags: tezos-client, transactions, tezbox, kt1, xtz

3 years ago I delegate XTZ to a baker using TEZBOX. Today I found out that the TEZBOX wallet is not available. I migrated to Temple wallet using a Privat Key, but now I have 0 XTZ on my balance, all my money is on a smart contract KT1, which has been not active since Sep 2021.  When I try to Import an account using Managed KT, I get an error: You are not a contract manager. Please help

Comment: Thank you, I transfered to Temple Wallet using the seed. I also moved 1 XTZ to tz1 account. On blockchain is show the balance =$1, but in wallet is 0. I tried to coonect to tezBox wallet, but get error: No connection

Comment: Thank you, @iguerNL.

Comment: I tried to transfer to galleon wallet but the balance is also 0. TezBoz gives me an error no connection, so the only correct balance shows on blockchain

Answer (score 1):

> I have 0 XTZ on my balance

This is either due to the way you imported your private key (e.g. you imported a bad tz address, but this rather happens when using a seed, not when using a private key).

> but now I have 0 XTZ on my balance

Assuming you correctly imported your account/private key, the fact that you have 0 XTZ is not related to Tezbox, but rather to the fact that you likely emptied your account.

> all my money is on a smart contract KT1

You should get a few XTZ (less than 1XTZ), to interact with the KT1 and transfer back you assets to a tz1 (knowing that tz addresses are now (since a long time actually) delegatable).

Comment: Thank you, I transferred to Temple Wallet using the seed. I also moved 1 XTZ to tz1 account. On blockchain the balance =$1, but in the wallet is 0. I tried to connect to tezBox wallet, but get the error: No connection

Comment: I tried to transfer to the galleon wallet but the balance is also 0. TezBoz gives me an error no connection, so the only correct balance shows on the blockchain. any ways to transfer my coins?

Comment: ```I transferred to Temple Wallet using the seed``` You said in your main question that you used private key ... If you're using a seed, it means that you are not restoring the same account on Galleon (seeds may be not just copy&paste between wallets).

Answer (score 0):

my temple wallet was disabled because of for 3 month I didn't use it and then I can't send any tezos and disable options (send, withdraw ....) how can you help me to improved pleased